# Recommended Webserver IDE and plugins to use with large GWT/Spring/JPA/Hibernate application

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, gwt, jpa

Before I go into any more details on the question I just want to give a quick overview of the scope and plan for the project to see what will suit it best:

- Large application, non-trivial
- 30+ DB tables
- User management/authentication/sessions
- Security BCrypt
- MVP (as per GWT recommendation)/GIN
- Focus on performance and scalability (naturally :), am using GWT after all)
- I am using maven to split the project up in a frontend part and back end
- GWT for frontend part (UI).
- Spring for the backend part :

  1. test driven development (TDD or BDD)
  2. Services interface and implementations
  3. JPA/Hibernate (dao)
  4. Orcale for the DB

I wast a lot of time in compiling and deploying this project like 10min for every change i made in my project.

my question is what are the best IDE(i am using eclipse kepler),Webserver(i have used tomcat and glassfish 3.0.1 but both give me permgen after the third times or less of the Deploying and Undeploying of my project)and methods to save a lot of time.

Comment: Have you tried it with increased max perm size as `-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m`.

Comment: nope i will try that but i already have a ram problem it only 4Go and when i compile with eclipse it stuck tell the end of the compilation

Comment: Try it with lesser memory `-Xmx256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m`

Comment: i followed Ümit advises and i use jetty with intellij idea 13 without any problem,thx Braj.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a similar project (regarding the scope) and I am currently using IntelliJ 13 Ultimate as IDE and Jetty as application server (via maven).

IntelliJ supports reloading changed classes without restarting the entire application server (at least for the server side code).
You can also check out [jRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/).

I would also recommend to debug client side code with `SuperDevMode`.

Comment: thx Ümit that was useful, i will search how to configure jetty with  maven in intellij 13 ultimate, and then see if i can use jRebel with this configuration for server side code, and finaly add a SuperDevMode for the UI debuging.

Comment: Ümit i have configured JRebel plugin for Maven in my root pom after i have installed JRebel,and IntelliJ 13 Ultimate as IDE and Jetty as application server (via maven),but when i do change a java class and compile it the the entire project begin to Recompile again.i am using jetty configuration with Jrebel.

Comment: IntellIJ has it's own recompiling mechanism. Make sure you disable it when you use jRebel. Check out this: http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/learn/intellij-idea-jrebel-tutorial-formerly-javarebel/